# How can I change the column count in android automatically based on the content of recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm working in Android Studio on a project, which has a quiz game with either images or text as answer options, depending on the question (both are just buttons in the xml file). Currently these buttons are shown in 2 columns but in case the buttons are displaying text instead of images the column count should be 1 because the button size has to be wider to show the whole text.

In my adapter the *onBindViewHolder* gets a list of answer options and sets the button content based on the option type (images/text). For some testing I've created the subclass *AutofitRecyclerView* of RecylerView to compute the number of columns automatically but that didn't solve my issue. Inside the *AutofitRecyclerView* I definded a *CenteredGridLayoutManager*. Furthermore I experimented with the method *setSpanSizeLookup* but that also didn't help.

**AutofitRecyclerView:**

```
public class AutofitRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private GridLayoutManager manager;
    private int columnWidth = -1;

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            int[] attrsArray = {
                    android.R.attr.columnWidth
            };
            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
            columnWidth = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
            array.recycle();
        }

        manager = new CenteredGridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);
        setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        if (columnWidth > 0) {
            int spanCount = Math.max(1, getMeasuredWidth() / columnWidth);
            manager.setSpanCount(spanCount);
        }
    }


    private class CenteredGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

        public CenteredGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        }

        public CenteredGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
            super(context, spanCount);
        }

        public CenteredGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
        }

        @Override
        public int getPaddingLeft() {
            final int totalItemWidth = columnWidth * getSpanCount();
            if (totalItemWidth >= AutofitRecyclerView.this.getMeasuredWidth()) {
                return super.getPaddingLeft(); // do nothing
            } else {
                return Math.round((AutofitRecyclerView.this.getMeasuredWidth() / (1f + getSpanCount())) - (totalItemWidth / (1f + getSpanCount())));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getPaddingRight() {
            return getPaddingLeft();
        }
    }
}
```

**Button-XML-File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="14dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_imgButton"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/option_imgButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/game_choose_answer_option_button_placeholder_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayout_imgButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraintLayout_imgButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraintLayout_imgButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout_imgButton" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_txtButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/option_textButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/freude"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="@string/game_choose_answer_option_button_placeholder_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title.Media"
            android:textColor="@color/forest"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayout_txtButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraintLayout_txtButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraintLayout_txtButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout_txtButton" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Recyclerview-XML-File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.lmu.treeapp.activities.minigames.chooseAnswer.GameActivity_ChooseAnswer">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/game_description_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_mid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />

    <de.lmu.treeapp.activities.minigames.chooseAnswer.AutofitRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/auto_fit_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_bot"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_mid" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What else can I do which I havn't seen right now? It may be better to provide 2 different xml layouts for the 2 different buttons, but I don't know how I can tell my recyclerView which layout xml it has to take.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framelayout and put both buttons in it and make both buttons gone. A framelayout would only display one single view so if the answer is a text you can only make the text button visible else you make the imagebutton visible.

Comment: Ok, I've now changed the layout to frameLayout but there is still the problem that both images and text are shown in two columns instead of differentiating between them.

In the _onBindViewHolder_ of my adapter I make a 
case distinction and set the respective button visible. Is there any option to clarify the column count at that point, or somewhere else? - Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've put the code of the frame layout below. The colums are now computed in the _AutofitRecyclerView_ class where a _GridLayoutManager_ is used to set up the _recyclerview_.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to determine the column number. Inside my adapter class, I wrote a method which gets a list of the current answer options and returns true if the type is *image*. In the *AutofitRecyclerView* class I replaced the method *onMeasure* with the following code in order to set the *spanCount* to either 1 or 2:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        if (columnWidth > 0) {
            int spanCount;
            if(RecyclerViewAdapter.isImage(RecyclerViewAdapter.options)){
                spanCount = 2;
            } else spanCount = 1;

            manager.setSpanCount(spanCount);
        }
    }
```

While I was testing around I've found out that it is very important to set a default value for *spanCount* before the method *onMeasure* computes new values.

Additionally I removed the *CenteredGridLayoutManager* and replaced it with just *GridLayoutManager* because my buttons already are centered.

Thanks anyway @Fadman, the *FrameLayout* helped me a lot. With the other layout my text buttons were shown with large white space between them because the invisible image buttons were also inside the respective container.

Answer (score 0):

**Layout xml of buttons:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/option_frame_layout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_img"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_txt"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/freude"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="@string/game_choose_answer_option_button_placeholder_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title.Media"
        android:textColor="@color/forest"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The visibility of both buttons is set to *gone* and will be changed in the code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use--> app:spanCount="3"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGaF4.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    app:spanCount="3"
    app:layoutManager="StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```